# Selecionar, trocar e ordenar itens em tabelas HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Estou tentando fazer um componente que me permita o seguinte: selecionar itens de uma tabela a esquerda e ao clicar em um item ela vá para a tabela a direita, na tabela a direita devo ser capaz de remover itens já adicionados a ela e reordená-los manualmente, sera um componente para lidar com banners em Carrocel de sites para que assim entre diversos itens cadastrados selecione e ordene os itens da maneira que deseje, já que a ordem é definida pelo cliente.
Tentei selecionar em uma tabela com checkbox mas preciso que se posssa listar somente os selecionados atualmente e que também tenha uma barra de pesquisa pois rapidamente terá 200 a 300 itens cadastrados.
[Aqui um rascunho do que estou tentando fazer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9j2V.png)

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8388/que-erro-cometi-ao-formular-minha-pergunta?cb=1

Answer (score -2):

Encontrei uma solução

usando a função sortable do jquery fui capaz de criar uma tabela que pudesse reordenar, e com a função clone pude copiar as linhas da primeira tabela na segunda.

```
    var selecionados = []

function add(id) {
    if (!selecionados.includes(id)) {
        var img = $(`#img${id}`).html()
        var titulo = $(`#titulo${id}`).html()
        var row = `<tr id="sRow${id}">
                        <td>${img}</td>
                        <td>${titulo}</td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="remove(${id})">Remover</button>
                        </td>
                   </tr>`
        $("#selecionados").append(row)
        selecionados.push(id)
        $(".dragDropTable").sortable();

    }
}
```